# How do output each of the alphabet in sequence on its own line?

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I'm new to programming in general and my teacher is starting me out with simple bash scripts. I would like to do the alphabet in it's own line.  For example:

```
A
B
C
```

I would like to do the alphabet with out writing the entire alphabet.  Ive work with numbers for example:

```
seq 1 3 | while read a; do
   echo $a
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
printf "%s\n" {A..Z}
```

See: `help printf`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
echo -e {A..Z}"\n"
```

And if you want to remove the extra space before each letter, you can use the following:

```
echo -e {A..Z}"\n" | tr ' ' '\n'
```